# Upload video on fanpage via PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a little problem with my FB application. It's about that I always get error:

> {"error":{"message":"(#353) Missing video file","type":"OAuthException","code":353}}

with this code:

```
            $post_url      = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/xxx/videos?"
                    . "title=" . $video_title . "&description=" . $video_desc
                    . "&access_token=" . $access_token;
            $ch = curl_init();
            $data = array(
                'source' => 'http://x/upload/' . $name . '.' . $type,
                'file' => './upload/' . $name . '.' . $type,
                'type' => 'avi',
            );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            if (!$response)
            {
                print_r(Debug::vars(array(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch))));
            }
            curl_close($ch);
```

File exist, access_token is valid and is logged as a app, In `$data` I've tried set only 'file' or 'source' but effects was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are best off using the Facebook PHP SDK for this, but it might be as simple as removing your file param and adding "@" to your source path. Here is a working example with the SDK (**assuming you have asked for the appropriate FB permissions**):

```
$this->facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$upload = $this->facebook->api('/me/videos', 'POST', array(
    'source' => '@'.$file,
    'title' => $title,
    'description' => $description
));
```