# Facebook Login by PHP-sdk not working for any other user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to implement posting videos on a fan page on facebook. But before doing that I am facing a problem as no other user is able to login using facebook rather than me. Anyone who tries to login by facebook through my website gets this error:

```
App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.
```

I have searced a lot about this error but I am unable to figure out why is this happening. My application is live and I am not trying it from localhost. You can see the demo [here](http://bizmoapps.com/test/).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: go to your facebook app and set "sandbox mode = disabled" also show what you set options in your app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your facebook app:-

enter

```
app domain = bizmoapps.com
sandbox mode = disabled
site url = http://bizmoapps.com/test/
```

for login process these field required there are so many options for different works with an app.
for more info http://faceconn.com/create-facebook-application

Comment: Sorry but I am unable to find the `sandbox mode`. Can you please guide me where it appears?Rest all the setting have been the same.

Comment: have you find settings tab? and set app in live mode

Comment: Yes I found it it was under staus and reviews tab. Thanks its working now :)

Comment: Can you please help me in one more problem of mine? its related to posting videos on facebook fan page.

Comment: please post another question and show your code what you have done and what error you are facing

Comment: Actually I just want to know one thing in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/ url I am using publish video by php sdk. but what does `{video-data}` mean in this?

Comment: check this link it willl be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660817/upload-video-on-fanpage-via-php-api

Comment: i already saw this post n i have given the video url in `source` but it still gives me the error `You must select a video file to upload`

Comment: path is correct its http://bizmoapps.com/icstories/uploads/video/52e113c822271vid-20130707-wa0000.mp4

Comment: please rename your filename with short and easy or try to post an image if works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45974/discussion-between-rakesh-sharma-and-user2936213)

Comment: @RakeshSharma I am having the same problem, but all my app settings seem to be set up well. you can see it here: http://apps.cbbnideas.com/kfc-demo/ -- I can access it as a developer, but anyone else cannot. They get this error. Please help

Comment: @RakeshSharma please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356180/facebook-app-log-in-error-when-made-live

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your Facebook Developer Account
2. Go to The FaceBook App
3. Check the sandbox mode is disabled or not? If not please disabled it. Wait for few minutes and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the UI of the facebook has changed recently, here's the latest update for setting the sandbox mode ON/OFF :

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/
2. Click on the Apps menu on the top bar.
3. Select the respective app from the drop down.
4. Go to 'Status & Review' from the table in the left side of the page.
5. Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? - Select switch to set YES/NO value.

Comment: Thanks but I have already done with this issue and accepted the answer also :)

Comment: SO is not meant for a single user. Other users looking for solutions on similar issues can refer to it in future.

Comment: I know and I have mentioned the path also you can read it in my comments.SO is also not meant to answer the question so late that too if user has found the answer already.

Comment: @user2936213 Answers can change from time to time depending on API/Third party changes. It is good to give future answers to let people become aware of this.

Comment: Yeah I know but girishvr has given the same answer, its nothing updated.